# JSTL into CSS file

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have 3 jsp:

- **template_blank.jsp**
- **template_connected.jsp**
- **template.jsp**

This jsp call a css file --> **commun.css**

this is the call in **template.jsp** for Example:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html:base ref="site"/>
<html:html>
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <tiles:useAttribute id="title" name="title"/>
        <title><bean:message key="${title}"/></title>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<html:rewrite page="/css/commun.css"/>">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icone.ico" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<html:rewrite page="/javascript/commun.js" />" ></script>
        <!-- Start of user code for header -->
        <jsp:include page="/javascript/generic/messages.jsp"/> 
        <!-- End of user code for header -->
    </head>
    <body>
....
```

This is my **commun.css**:

```
/* Start of user code for commun.css */
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<c:set var="headerHeight" value="156" />
<c:set var="footerHeight" value="0" /> /* 95 */
<c:set var="menuWidth" value="180" />
<c:if test="${height == null}">
    <c:set var="height" value="500" />
</c:if>
<c:if test="${width == null}">
    <c:set var="width" value="500" />
</c:if>
<c:set var="contentHeight" value="${height - footerHeight - headerHeight}" />
<c:set var="contentWidth" value="${width}" />
<c:set var="contentWidthConnected" value="${width - menuWidth}" />
<c:set var="tabHeight" value="27" />
<c:set var="contentHeightWithTab" value="${contentHeight - tabHeight - 1}" />

div#errors UL {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.fontAlerte {
    color: #006039;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.field_error {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
....
```

You can see **JSTL** into my **css**. It is used to define different `height`and `width`.
The problem is the **css** is performed after the **html** display.

so I have a display problem that produces a blinking effect on every call a new page. Is it possible to improve this behavior?

Comment: have a look into css preprocessors. if you dont have time for it, move the stylesheet content inside the jsp page - rather than having it as external style sheet

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan i copy all the css into `<head>` ... `</head>` or just the **jstl** code ?

Comment: just put the entire  css content inside head style tag

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan 
it's a little better but the css is too large for me to put it in my jsp

Comment: not only that - you lose externalisation. you might have to edit style in each jsp file for a single css change. why do you want jstl in css ?

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan my jps display correctly but i have no images, so there is no blinking effect i suppose 
the problem is compared to resizing images

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan **JSTL** is use i supose to resize image file in the `css`

Comment: browser only understands HTML + javascript + css. so if you want to achieve dynamic re sizing, better to do using javascript+css

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan how can i adapt my code in the `css` into js ?

Answer (score 0):

Your ordering seems off. I'm unclear on specifically what is JSP and what is meant to be JS content but suffice it to say you should attempt to delay your JS loading as long as you can (i.e. wait until just before the end of your <body> tag).

```html
<html:base ref="site"/>
<html:html>
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <tiles:useAttribute id="title" name="title"/>
        <title><bean:message key="${title}"/></title>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<html:rewrite page='/css/commun.css'/>">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icone.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Start of user code for header -->
        <jsp:include page="/javascript/generic/messages.jsp"/> 
        <!-- End of user code for header -->

        <!-- other body code here -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<html:rewrite page='/javascript/commun.js' />" ></script>
    </body>
  </head>
</html:html>
```